# Why doesn't "systemctl status" show anything ("journal has been rotated"), while journalctl shows entries dating back to March?

Tags: systemd, logs

There are two failed systemd units:

```
~: systemctl --failed
  UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                               
● shadow.service               loaded failed failed Verify integrity of password and group fil
● systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules
[...]
```

When I try to see what's wrong with `systemd-modules-load.service`, I get:

```
~: systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset>
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-07-07 12:33:57 CEST; 22min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 327 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 327 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable
```

However, using `journalctl`, I get:

```
~: journalctl -u systemd-modules-load.service 
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-26 15:17:39 CET, end at Sun 2019-07-07 12:52:59 CEST. --
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd-modules-load[321]: Inserted module 'crypto_user'
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd-modules-load[321]: Failed to find module 'vboxdrv'
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd-modules-load[321]: Failed to find module 'vboxpci'
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd-modules-load[321]: Failed to find module 'vboxnetadp'
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd-modules-load[321]: Failed to find module 'vboxnetflt'
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=>
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-c>
Mär 09 15:02:22 toastbrot systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Reboot --
Mär 21 10:30:08 toastbrot systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Succeeded.
Mär 21 10:30:08 toastbrot systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
-- Reboot --
Mai 08 17:59:03 toastbrot systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Succeeded.
Mai 08 17:59:03 toastbrot systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
-- Reboot --

[...]

-- Reboot --
Mai 14 22:27:51 toastbrot systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Succeeded.
Mai 14 22:27:51 toastbrot systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
-- Reboot --
Mai 21 12:10:37 toastbrot systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Succeeded.
Mai 21 12:10:37 toastbrot systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
```

I don't understand why `systemctl status` doesn't show anything (and tells the journal has been rotated), while `journalctl` shows entries dating back to March.

Comment: Uh…because the log has been rotated and systemctl only show recent in-memory logs?